# Setting ref parameters to a private method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Hello i'm new to coding and especially to unit testing and i'm trying to find a way to set two reference parameters to a private method in order to test it without changing any of my code, for example :

```
public class A
{

    public string RefPrivateMethod()
    {
        //some code that usually set the strings

        CompareTwoRefStrings(ref largerString, ref smallerString);

        return largerString;
    }

    private void CompareTwoRefStrings(ref string largerString, ref string smallerString)
    {
        int res = largerString.CompareTo(smallerString);
        string temp;

        if (!(res >= 0))
        {
            temp = largerString;
            largerString = smallerString;
            smallerString = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how can i set the largerString and smallerString parameters from my test.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile ...

Comment: The unit you should be testing is the class and the public interface it presents, not individual methods.  Therefore, your unit tests shouldn't even know or care that `CompareTwoRefStrings` exists.

Comment: @CorryM, show how you set them now

Comment: first of all it compiles when the reference params are set, and its not my real code only an example to make the question clearer.

Comment: how are you getting the strings - you should mock that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bit of a problem to know how to set the parameters through your test without knowing what is the code that is responsible of setting them usually.
although you can use Typemock, they have a feature that support assigning reference and out parameters. 
when using it your test would be something like that:

```
 [TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    A classUnderTest = new A();
    string larger = "blablablabla", smaller = "b";

    Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(classUnderTest,"CompareTwoRefStrings").AssignRefOut(smaller, larger).CallOriginal();

    var result = classUnderTest.RefPrivateMethod();

    Assert.AreEqual(larger, result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unit test is a *client* of your class. It exercises your class via *public interface* and verifies whether class behavior meets expectations. By *exercising* I mean trying various usage scenarios of your class.

What about private methods?

- Calling private method is *not an intended usage scenario* for your class. Some client can use disassembler to find private member details and then use reflection to call it. But it's not how classes supposed to be used. How many times did you call private members of `DateTime` class? I bet the answer is zero. Because you are using public interface which has documented and expected behavior.
- Any private member is an implementation detail. It can be renamed, refactored or removed any time. No guarantees. Using private members is unsafe for clients. Testing private members is time-wasting for you.

Your class has only one method in public interface - `RefPrivateMethod` (I hope real name is more meaningful). That's what clients will use. That's what you should test.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry CorryM,

I think you'll need to expose your `CompareTwoRefStrings` method publicly to be able to test it using unit tests.

You can write up Interface method that will do that for you so you do not compromise access levels for original(`CompareTwoRefStrings`) method.

It's only semantics, but unit tests should cover only fundamental functionality of the method. All other functionalities should be mocked so your tests do not fail due to failure of prerequisites. If you try to cover `RefPrivateMethod` (if that is a real method) then you'd not be writing unit test - but some form of integration test as you'd not be testing only logic for actual method but the `CompareTwoRefStrings` method as well as any other parts of the code that `RefPrivateMethod` invokes.

PS
There is also dirty way of testing private methods using reflection, but I would not advise such approach.